# local-first enterprise knowledge management software

Tags: wiki, knowledge-organization, knowledge-base

I'm in search of a local-first collaborative enterprise knowledge management / wiki software for Windows. The features I'm looking for are:

- WYSIWYG Editor.
- Data is stored on a local file server.
- Items can be interlinked.
- Files can be attached / embedded (e.g. PDF).

What I've tried so far is:

- Obsidian (lacks collaborative features and WYSIWYG)
- Logseq (lack collaborative features and WYSIWYG)
- MS OneNote (Software lock-in)
- DEVONthink (only available for MacOS)
- AnyType (looks promising but in BETA)
- AppFlowy.IO (looks promising but in BETA)

Comment: Looks like Joplin (https://joplinapp.org/) has a collaboration plugin: https://github.com/joplin/plugin-collaboration. Maybe this satisfies your needs?

Comment: Thanks for the hint @jmizv I'll look into it.

Comment: How about Zotero or Confluence? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zotero?wprov=sfla1 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluence_%28software%29?wprov=sfla1 You may find it useful to check the following article
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_reference_management_software?wprov=sfla1

Comment: Apart from Logseq and Obsidian, which you should probably revisit as they have synch features to aid collaboration, also check https://github.com/zadam/trilium